# Draw.io IIS Virtual Directory

Tags: iis, draw.io

I am struggling to make the necessesary configurations to run the Draw.io Asp.net samples (https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/dotnet/index.html). According to the docs  To run the ASP.NET examples in IIS, a virtual directory must be created that maps /mxgraph to the top-level directory of this distribution. To do this I have opened an IIS Manager and in `Default Web Site` I have added a virtual directory called `mxgraph` however, this did not solved the issue. Also, I have tried to create new Web Site in IIS and mapp to `mxgraph` folder which again di not work. Anyone has a clue how to make this work?

Comment: Did you get any error messages when you tried the above?